# GoogleApiClient in Fragment Android

Tags: android, fragment

I try to learn Android by myself. And in my app, I want to use fragment to show google map and when user open my app, I want to get current location by using `GoogleApiClient`
My fragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    public interface comuticateParent {
        public void sendMess(String text);
    }

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    comuticateParent callback;
    Button btn1;
    TextView textView;
    MapView mMapView;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                Log.d("onCreateView", Boolean.toString(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, 13));
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d("ConnectonStart", "Connected ");
        Log.d("ONstart", Boolean.toString(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("Connect", "Connected ");
        Log.d("onConnected", Boolean.toString(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d("Connect", "failed ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Activity activity;
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            activity = (Activity) context;
            callback = (comuticateParent) getActivity();
        }
    }

}
```

And problem here:
-Log in method onCreateView appears before log in method onconnected, so I can't get getLastLocation() because The googleAPIClient is not connect yet.

I have search in google but I don't know how to fix it. 
Please help me!
Sorry about my best English.

Comment: try to connect GoogleAPIClient in onCreate() method of fragment.

Comment: I move 'mMapView.getMapAsync' to onConnected and It worked. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem *Log in method onCreateView appears before log in method onconnected*, because `GoogleApiClient` will accessing Google APIs, verify app configuration, verify certificate fingerprint, etc. It take too long to process. To avoid blocking the UI thread, it'll execute in another thread and use asynchronous callback.

Second problem *I can't get getLastLocation() because The googleAPIClient is not connect yet*, because `FusedLocationApi` will only maintain background, so you need to get `GoogleMap` in background.

See my sample here: https://gist.github.com/quydm/a458d908c4da2496672f83372304f417

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wait until the `GoogleApiClient` has connected before you can request location updates. In order to do so, you would move this block of code (currently found in your `onCreateView()` method):

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
Log.d("onCreateView", Boolean.toString(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mylocation, 13));
```

to the body of the overridden method `onConnected()`.
You cannot have this code directly in `onCreateView()` because of the very problem you had. The connection must be established first before any location requests are sent. The connection can establish quickly or take longer than normal. It depends on many things outside of your control.

For that reason, I would suggest showing some sort of progress bar to indicate that location services is connecting and then remove the progress bar when `onConnected()` is called. Of course this depends entirely on your app. If location services is critical for the user to have then this is a must, if not, then you may not need to add it.